# Gradle searching for zip instead of jar

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-2.0

I want to include Apache commons-math 3.0 in my (Grails) project. So I put the following in my dependencies:

```
compile "org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.0"
```

It's in the central maven repository, see http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.0/

Gradle gives me the error

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.apache.commons#commons-math3;3.0!commons-math3.zip

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

and includes among others:

```
==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.0/commons-math3-3.0.zip
```

So it appears to be looking in the right place, but why is it looking for the zip instead of the jar? The Gradle doco says that jar is the default thing to search for. I even tried using "artifact only notation" with the @ sign to get the jar (as described at http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) but it still only searches for the zip.

Comment: Are you using an old (pre-1.0) version of Gradle? I recommend to try with 1.1.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Grails 2.1 - the latest.

Comment: I asked for the _Gradle_ version. Or are you using Grails' built-in build system? In that case, this is not a Gradle question.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser oops, sorry. Yes, I'm actually just using Grails. I thought that their build system is based on Gradle hence it would be more precisely a Gradle question? But I don't understand the Grails build system too much.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Grails' `BuildConfig.groovy` for resolution, there are two dependency resolution blocks, a `dependencies` block and a `plugins` block.  Make sure your declaration is inside the `dependencies` block.  If it is accidentally placed in the `plugins` block it will look for a packaged plugin, which are packaged as a `.zip` file.